# iPod Touch 4G Video and Music capacity

Tags: ipod-touch, video, audio

This must be my undeveloped mind, but browsing through Apple's iPod Touch website, I could not find the capacity (in time) for video and audio recordings on the 8GB and 32GB models (not in Features neither in Tech Specs).

I am debating which one to keep after buying the two at a discounted price. Have not opened it yet, so I can return one of them.

So, can someone point me to the place of this top-secret information?

UPDATE: To clarify the question - I am interested in the HD video recorded with the built-in camera. The intention is to replace the old P&S camera with this device. Thought that, if not Apple, maybe current users comment on that. A rough estimate is enough. Don't need a detailed to-the-last-byte calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time is based more on the size of the files versus a limit on the device. As in, You can only put (less than, due to OS and formatting, etc) 8 or 32GB (On a 8GB, usually you have a little over 6GB to play with, on 32 I think more like 29GB or so).

The 'time' capacity was just done using an average file size and the capacity. The same would be for 'songs' or 'videos' it can hold, like how iPod Classics were 20000 songs in your pocket.

Some quick notes found from a [random site](http://16gbipodtouch2g.info/how-many-songs-can-8gb-hold.html) while searching:

(For Audio)

> Well first of all with addressing
>   overheads , indexing etc actual
>   storage space is more like 7.95Gb 15Gb
>   and 29Gb respectively .Generally
>   speaking , the number of songs which
>   can be stored on your device depends
>   on the filesize of each song.No two
>   songs are the same size usually , a
>   number of factors can affect this. The
>   two main factors affecting the size of
>   an audio file arequality( Bitrate and
>   bitdepth) and time ( how long the song
>   is). Therefore to predict the  number
>   of songs your 8,32 or 16Gb Ipod Touch
>   can hold , a few assumptions will be
>   made based on the average user's mp3
>   listening practice. Here we will
>   assume each song is Cd quality
>   (44.1KHz sample rate) 128Kbps bitrate
>   and  4 minutes long i.e 3.75Mb per
>   song.   An 8Gb can hold about 2,120
>   mp3's songs A 16Gb drive could store
>   about 4,240 mp3's On a 32Gb drive you
>   could store about 8,480 mp3's

(For Video)

> Typically you can get a DVD movie at
>   700mb when you download it. This gives
>   On an 8Gb drive you could store about
>   10 movies On a 16Gb drive you could
>   store about 21 movies On a 32Gb drive
>   you could store about 44movies You can
>   compress the movie down to a much
>   smaller filesize and it will still
>   look good on the small screen ,
>   allowing you to cram many more movies
>   in there. Apple claims the Ipod Touch 
>   can hold up to 10 hours , 20 hours or
>   40 hours of video with the right
>   factors.Their claim is based on H.264
>   1.5-Mbps video at 640-by-480 resolution combined with 128-Kbps
>   audio.

As you can see, its not really an exact science of capacity of time. Same goes for CDR and DVDR's - the times are just estimations due to usual encoding and such.

I think Apple dropped this type of information from its advertising/tech specs because especially with the newer devices (which may need more space for OS) it would look like the storage capacity went down (as in, used to be x number of songs at y GB's, now x minus some number of songs at the same y GB's). The only one I see it on anymore is the iPod Classic, and if you have one with that large of a drive, you probably aren't counting much anymore either.

In your case I would probably keep the larger one (unless you need the money), because its never to bad to have extra space.

**Update**:
Do to the updated question (wondering about HD video recording), according to [this site](http://ipod.about.com/od/iphonevideoandmovies/qt/How-Much-Iphone-4-Video-Can-You-Record.htm), one hour of HD video is about 4.73GB. So with the 8GB you would get maybe less than an hour and a half, and with the 32GB about 4 hours.

[Another site has even more information on calculations](http://whenwillapple.com/blog/2010/06/11/with-iphone-4s-improved-camera-and-hd-video-should-i-go-32gb/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I am well aware of the capacity dependence on format and bit rate. My question was actually intended for HD video I record with the built-in camera. I will update the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Even with your update, it depends. Obviously the 32GB is going to be roughly 4 times as long. Updating answer with more info.

Comment: Thanks again. So, the combined information from the two links suggests somewhere between 4.5 and 6 hrs (give or take some) for the 32GB model, and around 1.5 hrs for the 8GB. It also suggest that for photo storage, around 11,500 and 3000 photos.