# How many HD video minutes do I get per 1GB of free storage?

Tags: ios, iphone, video

I have 7GB free. If I give that to someone to record, what sort of ballpark figure would I get for a HD video recording? There may be about 10 individual videos being recorded over a couple of hours, if that makes a difference. Maybe just one hour long one.

I just want to know a rough figure but ideally with some maths so I can work it out myself.

Comment: Somewhat a duplicate of http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15642/ipod-touch-4g-video-and-music-capacity

Comment: Doesn't look like a duplicate to me, @jmlumpkin. But it sure is related.

Comment: The reason I think it is a duplicate is the update to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The iPhone 4S takes video at 1080p and 30 fps and initial tests are showing that video takes 200MB per minute. At roughly 12 GB per hour, what seemed staggering a year ago is now quite quaint with the iPhone 4 recording at less than 5 GB / hour.

[MacWorld reports](http://www.macworld.com/article/152332/2010/06/iphone4_camera_video.html) that an hour of iPhone 4 video is 4.8 gig.

> The iPhone records its 720p HD video at around 10 megabits (Mbps) per second. That translates to about 80MB per minute, as we noted above, or a staggering 4.8GB per hour. (Hope you sprung for the 32GB model!)

Comment: No, I didn't get that version but I have way enough space to capture what I need - thanks! 4.8GB! Wow! Apple didn't mess about there!

Comment: That "hope you sprung" was from the article. I'm perfectly happy with my 14 GB iPhone 4.

Answer (score 1):

I just made a 15.5 minute test video with my iPhone 5S. File size is 1.31 GB, or 85 MB/minute. 7 GB of storage would handle 82 minutes of video.

Of course the complexity of the video and audio should have an effect on the compression, so this is just a rough guideline.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to estimate without looking at the footage first, or at least having a description of what will be shot (a crowd of people running around at Grand Central or 2 people sitting on a bench), the lighting conditions (night, with no lights, or day), the way it will be shot (on a locked tripod or over the shoulder, panning left and right like a maniac), etc...

Answer (score 0):

1gb from a

- Webacm-30 mins
- iPhone 5s-55 mins
- iphone 5-45 mins
- iphone 4s-30 mins
- iphone 4-27 mins
- iphone 3gs-23.5 mins
- iphone 3g-17 mins
- iphone 2-6 mins
- iphone 1-3 mins
- camera-1.25 hour
- film cam-3 hours

Answer (score -1):

It is scientifically proven that 1gb will take a 58 minute video for an iPhone 6.

Comment: This answer makes no sense as written.  Did you mean to say *a 58 minute video will take 1GB of space?*  Now, where is this "scientifically proven"?  If this is the case, you should provide links.  Also, what resolution?  I would bet a lower resolution would take less space than a higher one,  wouldn't it?